# Error in SSLCOMMERZ payment gateway using laravel for sandbox

Tags: ajax, laravel, payment-gateway

I followed all the the steps on how to implement the SSLCommerz payment gateway in laravel but i'm getting this error and i don't know what is wrong

```
Error!
Payment processing fails! Transaction is fail to generate
```

This is my code for making transaction using sandbox

```
public function payViaAjax(Request $request)
    {

        # Here you have to receive all the order data to initate the payment.
        # Lets your oder trnsaction informations are saving in a table called "orders"
        # In orders table order uniq identity is "transaction_id","status" field contain status of the transaction, "amount" is the order amount to be paid and "currency" is for storing Site Currency which will be checked with paid currency.

        $post_data = array();
        $post_data['total_amount'] = session()->get('checkout')['total']; # You cant not pay less than 10
        $post_data['currency'] = "BDT";
        $post_data['tran_id'] = uniqid(); // tran_id must be unique

        # CUSTOMER INFORMATION
        $post_data['cus_name'] = Auth::user()->name;
        $post_data['cus_email'] = Auth::user()->email;
        $post_data['cus_add1'] = 'Customer Address';
        $post_data['cus_add2'] = "";
        $post_data['cus_city'] = "";
        $post_data['cus_state'] = "";
        $post_data['cus_postcode'] = "";
        $post_data['cus_country'] = "Bangladesh";
        $post_data['cus_phone'] = Auth::user()->phone;
        $post_data['cus_fax'] = "";

        # SHIPMENT INFORMATION
        $post_data['ship_name'] = "Store Test";
        $post_data['ship_add1'] = "Dhaka";
        $post_data['ship_add2'] = "Dhaka";
        $post_data['ship_city'] = "Dhaka";
        $post_data['ship_state'] = "Dhaka";
        $post_data['ship_postcode'] = "1000";
        $post_data['ship_phone'] = "";
        $post_data['ship_country'] = "Bangladesh";

        $post_data['shipping_method'] = "NO";
        $post_data['product_name'] = "Computer";
        $post_data['product_category'] = "Goods";
        $post_data['product_profile'] = "physical-goods";

        # OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
        $post_data['value_a'] = "ref001";
        $post_data['value_b'] = "ref002";
        $post_data['value_c'] = "ref003";
        $post_data['value_d'] = "ref004";


        #Before  going to initiate the payment order status need to update as Pending.
        $update_product = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('transaction_id', $post_data['tran_id'])
            ->updateOrInsert([
                'name' => $post_data['cus_name'],
                'email' => $post_data['cus_email'],
                'phone' => $post_data['cus_phone'],
                'amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
                'status' => 'Pending',
                'address' => $post_data['cus_add1'],
                'transaction_id' => $post_data['tran_id'],
                'currency' => $post_data['currency']
            ]);

        $sslc = new SslCommerzNotification();
        # initiate(Transaction Data , false: Redirect to SSLCOMMERZ gateway/ true: Show all the Payement gateway here )
        $payment_options = $sslc->makePayment($post_data, 'checkout', 'json');

        if (!is_array($payment_options)) {
            print_r($payment_options);
            $payment_options = array();
        }

    }
```